# What are the useful attributes that can be used with passes in Yosys?

Tags: yosys

What are the most useful attributes that can be used with passes in Yosys?

Also, I was wondering if you could give me an example to set 'keep_hierarchy' for a specific module (namely "counter") using 'setattr'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README File](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/blob/master/README#L236) contains a list of the most prominent attributes. (Section "Verilog Attributes and non-standard features".)

Regarding `keep_hierarchy` and `setattr`: Consider the following example code.

```
module test(input A, B, output X, Y);
  test_and and_inst (.A(A), .B(B), .O(X));
  test_xor xor_inst (.A(A), .B(B), .O(Y));
endmodule

module test_and(input A, B, output O);
  assign O = A & B;
endmodule

module test_xor(input A, B, output O);
  assign O = A ^ B;
endmodule
```

Obviously the following would just display a schematic with a `$and` and a `$xor` gate:

```
yosys -p 'prep; flatten; opt -purge; show test' test.v
```

Now we can prevent flatten from flattening `and_inst` by setting the `keep_hierarchy` attribute on the cell:

```
yosys -p 'prep; setattr -set keep_hierarchy 1 test/and_inst; flatten; opt -purge; show test' test.v
```

Alternatively we can prevent all instances of `test_and` to be flattened by simply setting the attribute on the module itself:

```
yosys -p 'prep; setattr -mod -set keep_hierarchy 1 test_and; flatten; opt -purge; show test' test.v
```

Comment: Location of README file seems to be: https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/blob/master/README.md